# How can I remove duplicates in an array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i remove duplicates in an array like this?

My array $test1 gives me this out:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 14:36:32 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:38:51 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:07:43 )

)
```

My array $test2 gives me this out:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 14:36:32 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:38:51 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:07:43 )
[4] => Array ( [id] => 53241 [date] => 12-02-13 11:02:48 )
)
```

But I want the output to be that way with the latest date

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 53241 [date] => 03-02-13 11:02:48 )
)
```

What can i do?

Comment: If this comes from a database, I would do it in sql directly.

Answer (score 4):

```
$test1 = array ( 
    array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ), 
    array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ), 
    array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:38:51" ), 
    array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:07:43" )
);
$test2 = array ( 
    array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ), 
    array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ), 
    array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:38:51" ), 
    array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:07:43" ),
    array ( "id" => 53241, "date" => "12-02-13 11:02:48" )
);
foreach($test2 as $array) {
    if (!in_array($array, $test1)) {
        $new[] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Arrrh thanks @Antony. I hope you can answer this question to. What if I have two arrays as posted on top. A Test1 and Test2. How can I compare these arrays with each other and remove duplicates

Comment: Have a look at my solution and run the forloop twice, once for each array. Since the id's are stored in a separate array, both loops will know which id's are unique.

Comment: @Zaz Not sure what you mean by duplicate: is it the same id or both id and date are the same?

Comment: @Zaz - Have a look at my post, will post an edit in a moment.

Comment: @Antony & Husman: I just updated my question. You can se what i mean

Comment: @Zaz This is completely different from the original. Are you sure you want like that? See updated answer.

Comment: @Antony, heh. That i already know, but how can i get the "expected" output? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zaz Isn't that your "expected" output? Did you try that?

Comment: @Antony: sorry maybe it's me who has put me wrong. But I now have 2 arrays that I want compared. When it is compared, I want those who do not fit into an array list for themselves. They are the ones I call the "expected" output

Comment: @Zaz Still the above code would sort you out those that don't fit. I can rollback the previous answer for your previous question if you wish.

Comment: @Antony. There is no reason for it. In my array test1 I have 50 elements, where the array test2 I 89th I would now like to have the remaining 39 elements in an array for themselves.

Comment: @Zaz What about the first 50?

Comment: @Antony. Do not need them right now. Only the use of the remaining 39

Comment: @Zaz If so you don't need test1 since you can just extract the last 39 elements from test2, unless you have to compare their ids to tell if they are really different. In that case, you should better give me an example of how they look like.

Comment: @Antony. I just updated my posted question. Now this is a small example of my question

As you can see there are 4 values ​​in the array test1. But 5 values ​​in the array test 2 It gives me a difference of 1 value. I want it to be in an array for themselves.

Normally in this situation I would use array_diff_key

Comment: @Zaz But in your example the first 4 arrays are exactly the same. If you are certain of that and they are in order, there is no need to do any comparison and you can just go for the remaining arrays in test2.

Answer (score 3):

First merge the 2 arrays (from $test2 into $tes1 in this case):

```
foreach($test2 as $id=>$arr){
  $test1[] = $arr;
}
```

Then sort the $test1 by date (putting the oldest dates last, and newest dates first):

```
foreach ($test1 as $key => $row) {
    $orderByDate[$key]  = strtotime($row['date']);
}

array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_DESC, $dataArray);
```

Then remove the duplicates (This will keep the newest datetime and remove earlier ones)

```
$unique = array()
    foreach($test1 as $id => $arr){
      if( in_array($arr->id, $unique ) {
        unset($test1[$id]);
      }
      else {
        array_push($unique, $arr->id);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Or as someone else said, if this comes from a database, do it there. It is computationally cheaper to get SQL to do it, than to do it with PHP.

Comment: Just revised my solution. Test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using array_unique($test1)

Comment: The outout is this when i using array_uniqe: [0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 14:36:32 )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect_key` with `array_unique` and `array_map` for single line job:

In `PHP >5.3.0`:

```
$array = array ( 
    0 => array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ), 
    1 => array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ), 
    2 => array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:38:51" ), 
    3 => array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:07:43" )
);

$array = array_intersect_key($array, array_unique(array_map(function($n){ return $n['id']; }, $array)));

print_r($array);
```

`PHP <5.3.0`

```
$array = array ( 
    0 => array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ), 
    1 => array ( "id" => 47523, "date" => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ), 
    2 => array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:38:51" ), 
    3 => array ( "id" => 38639, "date" => "12-02-13 13:07:43" )
);

function mapArray($n){
     return $n['id'];
}

$array = array_intersect_key($array, array_unique(array_map("mapArray", $array)));

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own function beacuse array_unique is not for multidimensional arrays.

```
function array_unique_md($array)
{
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!isset($temp[$value['id']])) $temp[$value['id']] = $value['date'];
    }

    $your_structure = array();
    foreach($temp as $key=> $value)
    {
        $your_structure[] = array('id'=>$key,'date'=>$value);
    }

    return $your_structure;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$data = array_reduce($data, function($a,$b){
    isset($a[$b['id']]) or $a[$b['id']] = $b;
    return $a;
});

var_dump(array_values($data));
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/9598)